# Can we dynamically pass JSON object Key into a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Let's say I have a function which returns the value of a key I pass into it as a variable.

```
$scope.data = {"name":"Mayur","Age":25,"Location":"Pune"}    

$scope.showValue = function(key) {
  return  data.key   
}

showValue('name')  // it should return Mayur
```

I have sent key from html view and expecting it to return me its corresponding value.

Comment: Bracket notation: `data[key]`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/hz1xKazpKPA4FEED8hYC?p=preview